# How to create a Executable Jar for a non-web application with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, console-application, executable-jar

I am creating a Spring-Boot application for a non-web application and I would like to know what Plugin or procedure, I have to use.

For a Micro service development, the plugin to add in a `build.gradle` is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

But, when you execute the Jar generated, the jar start a Tomcat, and this kind of software is not required:

`java -jar consoleApp-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar demo=demo``

```
2017-08-30 14:48:13.505  INFO 82718 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-30 14:48:13.510  INFO 82718 --- [           main] spring.ParamLoader                       : Loading data...
2017-08-30 14:48:13.510  INFO 82718 --- [           main] spring.ParamLoader                       : item:
2017-08-30 14:48:13.523  INFO 82718 --- [           main] spring.ConsoleApp                        : Started ConsoleApp in 4.648 seconds (JVM running for 5.257)
^C2017-08-30 14:48:18.502  INFO 82718 --- [       Thread-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6477463f: startup date [Wed Aug 30 14:48:09 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

Any alternative?

Many thanks in advance.

Juan Antonio

Comment: You don't need anything else. What is started depends on the dependencies. If you don't include tomcat (or one of the other supported servlet containers) it will start as a non web application.

Answer (score 5):

What you have is a good start.

Now add the following dependencies to get all the Spring basics.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Then your main class can implement `org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner` and your app can start its work in the `run` method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Override 
  public void run(String[] args) {
    // do your work here
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

PS. If you have Tomcat starting first make sure your dependecy list does **NOT** contain `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: Hi @Strelok, the problem was as you said, the dependency.     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.6.RELEASE") previously:     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.6.RELEASE") when I removed the suffix: web, the app had an expected behaviour. Many thanks.